# My server error occured. (HTTP Satus Code: 504)?

Tags: http, nginx, centos

this is 8gb 4 core Simple Cloud Hosting server.
Here is my server monitoring chart. 
Chart of cpu load
[image]

Chart of memory usage
[image]

Chart of network traffic
[image]

Chart of nginx clients status
[image]

Comment: Recommend asking this on http://serverfault.com/ instead of here.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details about, your application, how is it configured, does it connects to other servers to serve a request ?

Comment: @user2393267  This is I wrote it myself a electronic mall, has been operating normally, today suddenly wrong, CPU load is very high, CPU occupancy rate is very big, but I see the traffic is low, but the high IO operations, will not be attacked?